# How to solve the "You can't use 'k' as an index because it's already defined" issue on Desmos Function Grapher?

Tags: desmos

My input is:

[image: formula input]

And I am using the [Desmos function grapher](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) which has an issue and the issue is that it alerts me on the third function:

> You can't use 'k' as an index because it's already defined.

But 'k' suppose to be **local** iterative variable defined inside the sum expression only and I expect that 'k' can be redefined, reused and reassigned also somewhere else.

How do I tell it that 'k' is local or to redefine, reuse and reassign it? Is this possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Desmos looks at your third expression, it sees something like (ignoring a lot):
[image: sum of k inside a sum of k]

Mathematically speaking, this would be bad notation, so Desmos throws an error. The developers put a lot of thought into balancing expectations of math teachers/students and programmers/computer scientists (c.f. [Logs and Infinities](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4yg1iqblrv)), and I think they made the right call here.

You can make use of the `total()` function to get [the result you want](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tibxcivylp):
[image: total([1...n])]